# Physics Principle of Curve Ball Dynamics

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, momentum, conservation-laws

My question is quite simple. When a ball is kicked or thrown in a way that it is spinning and make a curved trajectory, do any external forces acted on it?

In other words, if there is no external forces acted on the system, the linear momentum is conserved. Do linear momentum conserved in this case?

Because the ball keeps changing direction, thus the ball is accelerated. When a object is accelerated there exist net external force acted on it by Newton Second Law.

If there exist such a force, the force that make the ball changes direction is countered by a reaction force due to the Newton Third Law, does this force-pair considered into conservation of momentum discussion?

What is the specific example where clearly no doubt the linear momentum is not conserved?
Do I need to think really hard for this type of question like involving deep stuffs such as reference of frame, etc. I would like to focus just the ball itself. If I included the ball in too large system then it is not too meaningful, i.e., Linear Momentum always conserved much like energy always conserved.

Answer (score 0):

The momentum of the ball is not conserved because the air surrounding it exerts an external force on it. This is a "non intuitive" example, but it's equivalent to the more intuitive example of the velocity reduction of a ball thrown in air, due to air drag: the ball loses momentum since air exerts a force on it.

The conservation of momentum holds for the system composed by the ball and the air surrounding it. If the ball goes right, some air goes left.

Have a look at **Magnus effect**, as an example here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnus_effect

Comment: So basically we can just say that momentum of a defined system is always conserved if we included all force interactions into the system definition? Do external forces acted on the system that cause violation conservation of momentum are limited to gravity, drag, friction? Our actions (push/pull) on the ball are not considered external forces as it can be cancelled by reaction force by Newton Third Law and momentum still conserved for the system?.

Comment: Yes. What is internal force or external force really depends on the definition of the system and the external environment. If the system is ball+air, there is no external force, the overall momentum is conserved and the force acting on the ball is the opposite of the force that the ball exerts on the surrounding air (principle of action/reaction); if we look at the system to be only the ball, the force acting on it because it's moving in air is an external force that makes the momentum of the ball system change, changing the velocity of the ball (drag -> magnitude, Magnus effect -> direction)

Comment: So when we think about momentum of a system, we can safely think it is always conserved and don't need to bother to think when it is not conserved right?

Comment: No, you can't say that. Read the answer and the comments above without extrapolating

Comment: I've found so many commentary for example:
(1) Momentum is ALWAYS conserved within a closed system. The only time it appears to not be conserved is when there is a force acting from outside. In other words, your closed system is too small.

(2) Always. Conservation of momentum is well proven. Conservation of angular momentum is mostly true and until now hasn’t been disproven.

(3) When ever a question starts out:
“Would momentum be conserved …”
Just answer Yes!
Sometimes it’s a little tricky to figure out where it goes (Hint: The Earth)
But Yes.
Just Yes.